# Recyclerview in fragment not displaying alert dialog result right away

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

In my project I have a main activity with 3 fragments that are displayed via a ViewPager in a TabLayout on launch.  In one of my fragments I have a RecyclerView and a FAB that, when clicked, launches an alert dialog that captures user input to be displayed in the RV in the fragment.  Upon clicking ADD in the dialog, nothing appears in the RV but when I click the FAB and try again, it appears in the RV.  So what I am saying, I have to input info in the FAB twice before it displays in my RV in my fragment.  So I was wondering if someone could help me understand why this is happening.  It seems like my RV in my frag is not being created right away, but all in all my app is not crashing so I have no log to post.  I've research but to no avail.  I am self taught so any help would be appreciated.

**Fragment**

```
public class SubjectsFrag extends DialogFragment implements CardAdapter.ClickListener,
        SubjectsEditor.OnAddSubjectListener
{
    private static final String TAG = SubjectsFrag.class.getSimpleName();

    @NonNull
    Context context;
    private EditText titleView, teacherView;
    private String sTitle, sTeacher;
    public EmptyRecyclerView recyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    public CardAdapter cardAdapter;
    public SubjectsModel model = null;
    public ArrayList<SubjectsModel> subMod = new ArrayList<>();
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    @BindView(R.id.main_root)
    ViewGroup root;

    public SubjectsFrag() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subjects, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_sub);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

        titleView = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_subject);
        teacherView = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_subject_teacher);

        View emptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_subject_view);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(getContext(), subMod);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(cardAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void OnAddSubjectSubmit(String title, String teacher)
    {
        SubjectsModel model = new SubjectsModel(sTitle, sTeacher);

        model.setmTitle(title);
        model.setmTeacher(teacher);
        subMod.add(model);

        cardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    private void showDialog()
    {
        SubjectsEditor addSubjectDialog = new SubjectsEditor();
        addSubjectDialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        addSubjectDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), null);

    }
}
```

**Dialog Fragment**

```
public class SubjectsEditor extends DialogFragment
{
    Context context;
    private OnAddSubjectListener listener;
    @BindView(R.id.main_root)
    ViewGroup root;

    public interface OnAddSubjectListener
    {
        void OnAddSubjectSubmit(String title, String teacher);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            listener = (OnAddSubjectListener) getTargetFragment();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Calling fragment must implement onAddSubjectListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor_subjects, container, false);
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.editor_subjects, root);
        final EditText mTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_subject);
        final EditText mTeacher = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_subject_teacher);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Add Subject")
                .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final String sTitle = mTitle.getText().toString();
                        final String sTeacher = mTeacher.getText().toString();

                        listener.OnAddSubjectSubmit(sTitle, sTeacher);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

**Recycler Adapter**

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder>
{
    public ArrayList<SubjectsModel> subMod;
    private OnItemClicked onClick;
    static ClickListener clickListener;
    Context context;

    public CardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SubjectsModel> items)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.subMod = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardAdapter.CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        return new CardViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.subjects_item_list,
                parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CardAdapter.CardViewHolder holder, final int position)
    {
       SubjectsModel currentSubject = subMod.get(position);

        holder.titleView.setText(currentSubject.getmTitle());
        holder.teacher.setText(currentSubject.getmTeacher());
    }

    public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            View.OnClickListener
    {
        TextView titleView;
        TextView teacher;
        CardView cardView;

        public CardViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            titleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_subject);
            teacher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_teacher_text);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

            cardView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (clickListener != null)
            {
                clickListener.itemClicked(view, getAdapterPosition());
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.hello_blank_fragment, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return subMod.size();
    }

    public interface OnItemClicked
    {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnClick(OnItemClicked onClick)
    {
        this.onClick = onClick;
    }

    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clicked)
    {
        CardAdapter.clickListener = clicked;
    }

    public interface ClickListener
    {
        public void itemClicked(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

**Fragment xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_root">


    <com.example.ashleighwilson.schoolscheduler.adapter.EmptyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_subject_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/no_subjects"/>

   </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_sub"
        style="@style/FAB" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class OverviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    CharSequence tabTitles[] = {"SUBJECTS", "TASKS", "CALENDER"};
    int numOfTabs = 3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_nav);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), tabTitles, numOfTabs);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        toggle.syncState();

        mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        setupDrawerContent(mNavigationView);

       /* FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        }); */

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
            {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        //DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_nav, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
            {
                selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.nav_grades:
                Intent gradesIntent = new Intent(this, GradesActivity.class);
                startActivity(gradesIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notes:
                Intent notesIntent = new Intent(this, NotesActivity.class);
                startActivity(notesIntent);
                break;
        }

        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51841492/5691878

Comment: hasn't worked so far...I think I have a logic problem somewhere.

Comment: Heck yeah this worked!! Thank you sooo much! I'd been stuck for days. @rbd_sqrl

Comment: @rbd_sqrl if you can post your comment as an answer I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `notifyDataSetChanged()` should do the trick. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51841180/how-to-refresh-recyclerview-when-i-click-the-dialog-button/51841492#51841492)

Comment: thanx again! really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Giving it a once-over, nothing jumped out. You can use either the debugger or [`Log.d(String, String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) calls to challenge your assumptions about what’s being called when. I’d take a closer look at when you call your adapter’s `notifyDataSetChanged()` and then at the `getItemCount` and `bind` or `createViewHolder` calls inside the adapter itself.